# what should be filled up so the code can run successfully?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;   

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
      List student = new ArrayList();
      student.add("123");
      student.add("ABC");
      student.add("70.8");    

      Iterator itr = listItr.iterator();

      while(itr.hasNext())      
      {
          System.out.println(itr.next()); 

      }
 }
```

}
  What should i write here Iterator itr = _________; in order to get an 
  output?

Comment: Please see [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/1361506)

Comment: Are you struggling to see where standard out (System.out.println) prints to?  I think this code will successfully print to standard out.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. What is `listItr`?

Comment: Please change the title and make sure address the issue more clearly and what you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate over nothing :

```
// specify a list type with <yourType>
List<String> students=new ArrayList<String>();
// fill up your list

// was Iterator it = listItr.iterator(); but listItr is nothing
Iterator<String> it=students.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generics aside, you only have to change this line:

```
Iterator itr = listItr.iterator();
```

to this:

```
Iterator itr = student.iterator();
```